# Empty cookiejar using SUDS

Tags: python, linux, soap, suds, cookiejar

I'm running SUDS 0.4 on Linux Slackware 13.0 with python 2.6.2. When I call SOAP method using this code:

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client(url='file:acctWeb.wsdl',
                location='http://10.242.69.4:8088/pfmaccess')

res = client.service.login(login='user',password='passwd')
```

I receive following response:

```
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:received:
CODE: 200
HEADERS: {'set-cookie': 'OSP_Ref=0000000573800052;Domain=10.242.69.4:8088;Path=/pfmaccess', 'content-length': '26541', 'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'connection': 'close', 'server': 'Alcatel-Lucent OSP 2.4'}
```

but

```
>>> client.options.transport.cookiejar
<cookielib.CookieJar[]>
```

shows that there are no cookies available. What could be a reason for that? I'm not able to use SOAP API because I need to pass credentials sent in response cookie.

Please help me on this.

BR

rjan

Answer (score 7):

Ok, i've played around a bit with it.

first, a little test server ([courtesy of soaplib](http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/pages/helloworld.html)):

```
import soaplib
from soaplib.core.service import rpc, DefinitionBase, soap
from soaplib.core.model.primitive import String, Integer
from soaplib.core.server import wsgi
from soaplib.core.model.clazz import Array
import sys, pprint

class HelloWorldService(DefinitionBase):
    @soap(String,Integer,_returns=Array(String))
    def say_hello(self,name,times):
        results = []
        for i in range(0,times):
            results.append('Hello, %s'%name)
        return results

class WsgiApp(wsgi.Application):

    def on_wsgi_return(self, env, headers, return_str):
        headers['Set-Cookie'] = 'spam=eggs;domain=127.0.0.1;path=/'
        print >>sys.stderr, headers

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
        soap_application = soaplib.core.Application([HelloWorldService], 'tns')
        wsgi_application = WsgiApp(soap_application)
        server = make_server('localhost', 7789, wsgi_application)
        server.serve_forever()
    except ImportError:
        print "Error: example server code requires Python >= 2.5"
```

with some little modification to set a cookie header.

and a suds-testclient:

```
from suds import client, transport

c = client.Client("http://127.0.0.1:7789/?wsdl")
print c.service.say_hello("spam", 1)
print c.options.transport.cookiejar
```

running this produces:

```
(stringArray){
   string[] = 
      "Hello, spam",
 }
<cookielib.CookieJar[<Cookie spam=eggs for .127.0.0.1/>]>
```

so it seams to work. but if you change the request url to `http://localhost:7789/?wsdl` you'll get:

```
(stringArray){
   string[] = 
      "Hello, spam",
 }
<cookielib.CookieJar[]>
```

turning on some logging for `cookielib` at the client...

```
import logging
import cookielib
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('cookielib').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
cookielib.debug = True
```

... and it reveals reveals why:

```
DEBUG:cookielib:add_cookie_header
DEBUG:cookielib:extract_cookies: Date: Thu, 17 May 2012 15:56:01 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Set-Cookie: spam=eggs;domain=127.0.0.1;path=/
Content-Length: 822
Content-Type: text/xml

DEBUG:cookielib: - checking cookie spam=eggs
DEBUG:cookielib:   effective request-host localhost.local (even with added initial
                   dot) does not end with .127.0.0.1
(stringArray){
   string[] = 
      "Hello, spam",
 }
<cookielib.CookieJar[]>
```

the simple explanation is: the cookie domain does not match the request's server domain, and as it seems `cookielib` does not do any lookup when verifying the domain.

so the solution would be one of:

- make sure client and server use the same domain (either domainname or IP)
  in the example i have to set both to `localhost.local` to make it work (may depend on the `hosts` file...)
- remove the domain from the sent cookie, then `cookieib` uses the request domain automatically
- implement a cookiejar that uses DNS lookups

Oh, and last but not least: the reason why it didn't work in the OPs question:
the port is not part of the domain, therfore a cookie with `Domain=10.242.69.4:8088` will always be rejected.